# drag & drop image onto text in contenteditable div deletes first letter of word in chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, contenteditable

Is this a bug in Google Chrome (Version 25.0.1364.97 m) ? ... it behaves as expected in Safari

If you first drag & drop some text into a contenteditable div.... and later drag & drop an  image or any element into that text ... not always but often ... if you drop the obj immediately before the first letter of a word ... that letter is deleted ...

any ideas ? ... here's example code...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
Is this a Bug in Chrome ?<br><br>
<div id="main" contenteditable="true" style="border:solid 1px black; width:300px; height:300px" spellcheck="false" ></div>
<br><br>


Select some text and drag it into the contenteditable box ...<br><br>

Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.
We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how:<br><br>

Then drag and drop an image into the text ...

<img width="50px" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f7b22b86b0da570ddb5d1d4923b0f4f4" alt="">
<img width="50px" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmjD0kayL4VTZqfYDNavlQuNvOaBd4o4HjrnNlgbNhUfVy5QfrLg" alt="">

and drag and drop it around ...<br><br>
If you drop it right before the first letter of a word ... often it deletes that first letter in Chrome ???<br><br>

Any Ideas ?

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Catched the same bug. 
I don't know whether it's Chrome bug or not, but here's my workaround: try to wrap every word in your sentence in <span>.
 It helped me!